# Proof of uniqueness of predual of von Neumann algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am currently reading Jesse Peterson's [lecture notes on von Neumann algebras](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/peters10/teaching/spring2013/vonNeumannAlgebras.pdf). I'm confused by lemma 4.4.2. In particular, it seems to me that Hahn Banach theorem here can only conclude the map $\phi$ is in the X** not in X. Without this it seems the subsequent proof of uniqueness of predual of von Neumann algebra cannot go through. Can somebody help? Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't read Peterson's notes, but I can tell you that Sakai's original paper proving uniqueness of the predual is pretty readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is using the version of the Hahn-Banach theorem which works for locally convex spaces.  We have a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and a Banach space $X$ with $X^*=A$.  We then equip $A$ with the weak$^*$-topology, that is, $\sigma(A,X)$.  As the proof notes, $(A)_1 \cap A_+$ is $\sigma(A,X)$ compact, so if $a<0$ we can find a $\sigma(A,X)$-continuous linear functional which separates.  But $\sigma(A,X)$-continuous linear functionals are simply elements of $X$.

I agree that this is a little unclear in the proof.  What's a good book for the Hahn-Banach theorem at this level of generality?  You could look at Rudin, Functional Analysis.  Or I really like Conway's Functional Analysis.  I think Theorem 3.9 of Chapter IV in the 2nd edition is enough.  I'm afraid I don't know a good online resource (can anyone suggest one?)

Comment: I don't know an online resource either, but these statements can be found in Schaefer's *Topological Vector Spaces* as II.9.2 and IV.1.2, and also somewhere in the first volume of Dunford and Schwartz. The statement that $\sigma(A,X)$-continuous linear functionals all come from elements of $X$ is itself not trivial unless you know to use the definition of continuity of linear maps in terms of neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I understand the proof now.